# Why do mappings exist in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

From what I read, Elasticsearch is dropping support for types.
So, as the examples say indexes are similar to databases and documents are similar to rows of a relational database.

So now, everything is a top-level document right?

Then what is the need for a mapping, if we can store all sorts of documents in an index with whatever schema we want it to have.

I want to understand if my concepts are incorrect anywhere.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch is not dropping support for mapping types, they are dropping support **for [multiple mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) within a single index**. That's a slight, yet very important, difference.

Having a proper index mapping in ES is as much important as having a proper schema in any RDBMS, i.e. the main idea is to clearly define of which type each field is and how you want your data to be analyzed, sliced and diced, etc.

Without explicit mapping, it wouldn't be possible to do all the above (and much more), ES would guess the type of your fields and even though most of the time it gets it right, there are plenty of times where it is not exactly what you want/need.

For instance, some people store floating point values in string fields (see below), ES would detect that field as being `text/keyword` even though you want it to be `double`.

```
{
    "myRatio": "0.3526472"
}
```

This is just once reason out of many others why it is important to define your own mapping and not rely on the fact that ES will guess it for you.

Comment: So the way I am currently writing my mapping, is that I have tried to store different types of schemas under the same Index. Something like this: https://ideone.com/cmRy7Z. 


Is this the right way to be doing this?


One problem that I have faced is that, when I try to query all my documents in an index, it only returns all documents associated with a single schema (`message` in my case), even though I have inserted documents of different schemas in the database (`chat`, `top`, `user`).

Comment: No it's not really the right way, you should create one specific index for each entity type you have (`message`, `user`, etc). An index is not a database, but more like a table. Your cluster is the database and documents inside an index are like rows inside a table. All rows in a table have the same RDBMS schema, right? The same goes for ES

Comment: To be more specific, the CURL call I am making to fetch all documents is with:
http://localhost:9200/app/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*

Comment: alright, noted. So the inconsistency I am facing (while fetching all documents) might be due to storage of multiple schemas within the same index?

Comment: You have a single schema in your index, not several, but each of your document contains a different set of data (which bis why they belong to different indexes). In your curl call, you don't have the `size` parameter (default 10) so you're probably getting the first 10 documents which happen to all contain `message` data