# Why do we create mapping in elasticsearch while setting up repository?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Okay, I got it [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261575/why-do-mappings-exist-in-elasticsearch) that what is the need for mapping.

Now I am going through a piece of code, what they are doing is that they are generating the mapping while creating the elastic search repository by pushing a dummy object and then deleting it.

I got it that elastic search can generate mappings, but what is the point of doing so. It does not help with the search queries ( at least the regex one that I have tried unless you explicitly tell in your mapping that this is of type keyword).

I would be thankful if someone can explain this.

Comment: Instead of calling repository, you should call it index :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed :) thanks for reminding !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Elasticsearch generates the mapping when you don't define one, and just index the document, but that way Elasticsearch generates the mapping based on the first document data, for example you have `product-id` field in your index, and if you index it without defining explicit mapping, Elasticsearch generates two data-type, one is `text` and another is `keyword` for this field when you index `product-id` as below.

```
{
"product-id" : "1"
}
```

Now, it depends on your use-case, let's suppose in your case, `product-id` is keyword and fixed, and you just want to use the `exact search` or `aggregation` on the `product-id` field, and don't want the `full-text search`, than you better go with explicit mapping and define it as in `keyword` field, that way Elasticsearch storage and queries would be optimal. You can refer to this [Stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327447/elastic-search-lowercase-analyser-does-not-return-search-result/71331811#comment126086964_71331811), for more information on it.

**Bottomline, When you want to have a greater control on how your data should be indexed, It's always better to define explicit mapping than relaying on default mapping generated by Elasticsearch.**

Comment: I have a field "name", I want to carry out both exact search and full-text search (regex) query on it. What should I do ? Secondly the code I am going through generates it at the time of index creation by putting in a dummy document, is it necessary to do so ? Third, i am going through FilterBuilders, I am not able to get the difference between inFilter and TermFilter, can you please guide me on this ?

Comment: got the first answer : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/multi-fields.html

Comment: @AbhinavBatta thats too many follow-up questions :), first one you got it, and second one, its not necessary to insert a dummy document, and you should avoid that if you want fields mapping according to your need. third one, as its unrelated question in current context, I would advise to ask new question on it with all details.